# IUser<TKey> in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to authenticate user against existing database. I found that I need to implement IUserStore. I am trying to create Custom User implementing IUser, I can find IUser is in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity assembly. Is there equivalent interface in asp.net core?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: there is [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html)

Comment: @qbik That is using EntityFramework. The code provided there uses ApplicationUser that is in Microsoft.AspNetCore.EntityFrameworkCore assembly.  I am trying to implement authentication without entityframework dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just been Googling for the same and I have found this closed issue on GitHub https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/948

From the comments it seems that the interfaces don't exist, but we still have to provide the methods on our `UserStore`... sounds a bit confusing to me.

I have also found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie which describes cookie middleware without ASP.NET Core Identity.

These are also good reading https://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-authentication-with-asp-net-core/ and https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-cookieauthenticationmiddleware-in-asp-net-core/